# run android emulator headless with jenkins on debian

Tags: jenkins, debian, kvm, headless, android-virtual-device

I want to run espresso tests in the emulator by a jenkins task on headless debian. I also use it to take screenshots for publishing.

Jenkins build fails with the following messages:

```
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/android list target
[android] Using Android SDK: /opt/android-sdk-linux
[android] Setting hardware properties:
    hw.ramSize: 1536
    vm.heapSize: 128
    hw.gpu.enabled: yes
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5826 *
* daemon started successfully *
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb start-server
[android] Starting Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -ports 5824,5825 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_480_1920x1080_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_22_google_apis-x86_64 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 POPCNT
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
[android] Emulator did not appear to start; giving up
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb disconnect localhost:5825
[android] Stopping Android emulator
$ /opt/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/adb kill-server
[htmlpublisher] Archiving HTML reports...
[htmlpublisher] Archiving at PROJECT level /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/PublishCupido/PingAndroidClient/build/spoon/release to /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/PublishCupido/htmlreports/Screenshots
Finished: NOT_BUILT
```

I assume this is caused by a timeout due to very slow emulation.

When I start emulator by command line I see:

```
/opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator -ports 8196,8197 -prop persist.sys.language=en -prop persist.sys.country=US -avd hudson_en-US_480_1920x1080_Google_Inc._Google_APIs_22_google_apis-x86_64 -no-snapshot-load -no-snapshot-save -no-window -show-kernel
emulator: WARNING: Host CPU is missing the following feature(s) required for x86_64 emulation: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 POPCNT
Hardware-accelerated emulation may not work properly!
Failed to open lib64EGL_translator
Failed to init_egl_dispatch
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES initialization failed!
emulator: ERROR: OpenGLES emulation library could not be initialized!
emulator: WARNING: Could not initialize OpenglES emulation, using software renderer.
Killed
```

I can't do much about the missing CPU features, can I???

But it should be possible to get GPU running.

```
# ldconfig -lv /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/lib64EGL_translator.so 
    lib64EGL_translator.so -> lib64EGL_translator.so
# ldconfig -p | grep lib64
    lib64EGL_translator.so (libc6,x86-64) => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib64EGL_translator.so
```

but:

```
# ldconfig -v | grep lib64
ldconfig: Can't stat /lib/i486-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Can't stat /usr/lib/i486-linux-gnu: No such file or directory
ldconfig: Path `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: Path `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu' given more than once
ldconfig: /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring

ldconfig: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.13.so is the dynamic linker, ignoring
```

Creating the link manually does not change anything:

```
# ln -s /opt/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/lib64EGL_translator.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
# ldconfig
```

1. Is my CPU to old for KVM?
2. How can I provide the missing library?
3. What else can I do to speed up emulation?
4. How can I increase/avoid timeout?
5. What else can I do to use emulator with jenkins?

Thx

Comment: did you manage to solve this?